# How can I replace multiple tables into Divs?

Tags: jquery, html

In my code below the second table does not keep the same code it appears to be overwritten by the code from the first table.

Is there a way so that I can preserve the code yet still replace my tables to be div's and spans?

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()
       .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
       .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='ccbnOutline'")
       .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
       .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
       .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
       .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
    );

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <!-- This will be changed into div's and span's -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End of Example Table -->


            <!-- This will be changed into div's and span's -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>one123</td>
    <td>two123</td>
    <td>three123</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End of Example Table -->
```

Comment: So you want to keep the second code table, but change the first? What exactly do you want preserving?

Comment: I'm looking to keep the one123 and not have it disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are replacing multiple objects with content of multiple objects.

Here a fixed version:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table').each(function (){
            $(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
                .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
                .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='ccbnOutline'")
                .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
                .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
                .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
                .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I made it run through an .each loop and replaced the items one by one with the corresponding table.

Comment: Thanks Daniël that was what I was trying to do.  I even had it written out it just didn't function. I probably defined it wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You should loop through the different elements and generate your own html, rather than doing `.replace` -- using regex is generally bad practise for dealing with HTML structures. The below code works:

```
$('table').replaceWith(function() {
    var html = '';

    $('tr', this).each(function() {
        html += '<div class="ccbnOutline">';
        $('td', this).each(function() {
            html += '<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
        });
        html += '</div>';
    });

    return '<div class="table">' + html + '</div>';
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HRYEQ/1

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Just replace 
`$('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()`
 in your code with

`$('table:first').replaceWith( $('table').html()`.

Comment: But I'm trying to replace all tables with div's and have one be <div>one</div> and another be <div>one123</div>