# Change all TABLE elements to DIV inside the TD tag only jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `TABLE` structure that i want to convert its element to `DIV` using jQuery Function

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
             <table>
                <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td>1000+</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>$0.115</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>2000+</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>$0.106</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>5000+</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>$0.099</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>10000+</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>$0.092</td>
                       </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The structure I only want to replace is those table who's inside the cell (`TD`) tag. So made a code to filter and replace only those table that reside inside the `TD` tag

```
$('table td:has(table)').replaceWith(function() {
           //Replace function starts here
})
```

The thing is i want to replace all elements like `<TABLE>`,`<TBODY>`,`<TH>`,`<TR>` and `<TD>`into `<DIV>` or `<SPAN>` element.

How can I be able to achieve this?

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div>
    <div>
        <div>
                <div>1000+</div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><div>$0.115</div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <div>2000+</div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><div>$0.106</div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <div>5000+</div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><div>$0.099</div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <div>10000+</div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><div>$0.092</div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to replace an entire `<table>` with one `<div>`, so please give an example of your desired output. (Presumably you want individual divs replacing the tds, or something like that?)

Comment: ok ill add a sample desired output to the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141856/how-can-i-replace-multiple-tables-into-divs    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229856/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-convert-an-html-table-into-divs might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$("#me").click(function(){
    var innerhtml = $("table tr td").html();
    var innerhtml = innerhtml.replace(/table/g, "div");
    var innerhtml = innerhtml.replace(/tbody/g, "div");
    var innerhtml = innerhtml.replace(/tr/g, "div");
    var innerhtml = innerhtml.replace(/td/g, "div");
    $("table tr td").html(innerhtml);
});
```

It grabs the HTML from inside your table and replaces all instances of "table", "tbody", "tr", and "td" with "div".

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WXDjR/)

Comment: how to make this on .each function?

Comment: @Onimax This will affect all instances where the parent tree is table -> tr -> td.  Do you have other instances where you want the table elements replaced?

Comment: well there is.. anyway, i used this code on adding classes to the table i wanted:

    `$('table td:has(table)').each(function(){
    return $('td > table').addClass('red');
    })`

then i used `$(".red").each(function()` to change the table elements to div. that things worked.